# how to consolidated database connection into one file in php

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

I currently using two different connection file to my web based.

So, I want to reduce and consolidate both connnection file into one.

connection.php just simple connection file while tablemodel.php used to fetch data from database and show the table in table.

Looking for the solution. Thanks!!

connection.php

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","mydatabase");
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Please Check your connection'/mysqli_error($conn));
    }
?>
```

tablemodel.php

```
<?php
class Model
{
private $dbHost = 'localhost';
private $dbUser = 'root';
private $dbPass = '';
private $dbName = 'mydatabase';
private $conn ;

public function __construct(){
   try {
        $this->conn = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $this->dbName);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            echo "Connection error " . $th->getMessage();
        } }

public function fetch_res(){
        $data = [];
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT  `name` FROM `name_id`";
        if ($sql = $this->conn->query($query)) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                $data[] = $row;
            } }
        return $data;
    }}
?>
```

Comment: You are not connecting properly. You should enable error reporting and set the proper charset.

Comment: You made it a thousand times worse. Now your code creates as many connections as many instances of the model class is made.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Means my tablemodel shouldn't write the connection? just use connection.php as the main connection file?